Documentation for SonataAdminBundle v2 (2.4)
I need to make some changes on an old website before migrating it to a newer version of Symfony + Sonata Admin, but I cannot find the doc for the v2 (more specificaly 2.4) of the SonataAdminBundle, do you know where I could find it ?
Thanks by advance !

I'm afraid it doesn't exist.
